# Display text on page with specific tag in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display a text with a specific tag in wordpress.

Ex: I have 2 tags: car and boat, and 2 text: "I have car and i want one bike", "I have boat and i am happy"

I want to display in header specific text when exist tag.

I try using tem exist in header.php but display text in all pages, not just in page where exist tag.

Ex:

```
 <?php
$boat = term_exists('boat', 'post_tag');
if ($boat !== 0 && $boat !== null) {
  echo "I have boat and i am happy!";
}
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only two tags this will do.

```
<?php 
if (is_tag( 'boat' )) {
    echo "I have boat and i am happy!";
} elseif (is_tag('car'))   {
    echo "I have a car";
}
?>
```

Comment: Don`t work. No text displays.

Comment: Where did you place it?

Comment: I place it in header.php

Comment: I update the answer and tested. There was an extra semi-colon. The text is displayed on a tag archive page. If the tag name is either boat or car.

Comment: I want to show my text on page, where is the tag, not in the archive. I replaced in your code "is_tag" with "has_tag" and work great. Thank you.